# Let windows ignore a faulty drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have a secondary (non-system) hdd with some bad sectors. Whatever I try to recover the data (cloning, imaging, copying,...) seems to be failing because the OS fails (Windows 8 + Fedora Live). Win8 freezes completely and I have to do a hard reset, and Fedora crashes with a kernel panic.

Is there a way to access the faulty hdd without the OS interfering with it?

Comment: By booting from an OS that is NOT on that drive?

Comment: @Chris - The hdd with errors is the system disk or an additional non-system disk?  Any solution will require this not to be a system disk.

Comment: It's not the system disk (updated the question). Thanks

Comment: This is weird. The OS should not crash from just bad sectors. I've used Linux to recover data from bad drives, so Linux should handle this. Please post the commands you use on Fefora Live, and the exact kernel panic you get. Also, try a different Live CD to make sure it's not a problem with the Live CD.

Comment: @sleske - I have had similar experience.  Of course in my case it was not just bad sectors.

Comment: @sleske - I'm using `ddrescue --force /dev/sde3 /dev/sdb2 logfile.ddrescue`. I tried again but it doesn't show the shell anymore. Just a large grey rectangle in the top left corner of the screen, and I had to do a hard reset. I'm going to try with a different Live CD shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) and following this short [tutorial](http://jai-fixyourpc.blogspot.sg/2011/09/how-to-fix-bad-sectors-in-your-hard.html).